# Defining an interface and using multiple implemenations of the interface

Tags: python, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I had problems getting my head around the implementation for the following requirement:

1. Creating one interface class `Interface`.
2. Creating n classes `ImplementationN` that implement the `Interface` in different ways.
3. Creating one new class `UsingInterface` that uses the functions from `Interface` to define its own functions.
4. Creating n new classes that allow usage of the functions created in `UsingInterface` but implementing the functions used by `UsingInteface`'s methods by one of the `ImplementationN` classes.

The following is the solution I came up with:

Comment: What aren't you getting your head round? This is the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Comment: I wasn't sure how to implement this behavior in Python, but think I have managed to do it properly in the example below. Feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe post on [codereview.se] instead.

Answer (score 1):

Explaination in-line. One key in the solution was to set `UsingInterface` as `metaclass=ABCMeta` so it (in this case the IDE) doesn't require the implementation of `func1`.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class Interface(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    """Class that defines an interface."""
    @abstractmethod
    def func1(self):
        pass


class Implementation1(Interface):
    """Class that implements the interface one way."""
    def func1(self):
        print('func1 was implemented here')


class Implementation2(Interface):
    """Class that implements the interface another way, differently."""
    def func1(self):
        print('func1 was implemented here as well, but differently')


class UsingInterface(Interface,  metaclass=ABCMeta):
    """Class that uses the interface to implement its own functions.
    `func1` is not implemented here, hence this has to be an `ABCMeta` class.
    Later, the correct implementation of `func1` based on the inherited
    Implementation class shall be used.

    We're inheriting `Interface`, so the IDE can tell us which methods
    we can call (in this case `self.func1()`).
    """
    def func2(self):
        print("I'm running func1 from the Interface: ")
        self.func1()


class Usage1(UsingInterface, Implementation1):
    pass    


class Usage2(UsingInterface, Implementation2):
    pass

u1 = Usage1()
u1.func2()
# I'm running func1 from the Interface:
# func1 was implemented here

u2 = Usage2()
u2.func2()
# I'm running func1 from the Interface:
# func1 was implemented here as well, but differently
```